# Change Font Color for certain Words

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics

I use ultraTextEditor via Infragistics.

I want to find 'Select' word and make it for color to blue. How can i do this ?

```
if (uteSQL.Text.Contains("Select"))
    {
         // Make All 'Select' words blue       
    }
```

Comment: I think you can't change color of word instead of that what you can try to add those word to label control and you can change color of label  and moreover you can use panel control to add those labels and try that!

Answer (score 1):

UltraTextEditor does not provide such functionality. As you are using Infragistics controls you can switch to UltraFormattedTextEditor. In UltraFormattedTextEditor you can change the color of each Select word to blue like this:

```
var input = this.ultraFormattedTextEditor1.Value.ToString();
var result = input.Replace("Select", "<span style=\"color: Blue;\">Select</span>");
this.ultraFormattedTextEditor1.Value = result;
```